# Angularjs ng-click not working in laravel #PHP

Tags: php, laravel

**I have just created a very simple app. It only contains one function which is used in ng-click. Somehow, ng-click is not firing. Can anyone take a look for me?**

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="primary" style="padding-right:5px">Primary skill </label>
    <select id="primary" class="form-control" ng-model="primary" id="primary" ng-options="s.skill_name for s in skills| excludeFrom:secondary"></select>
    <label for="secondary">Secondary skill </label>
    <select id="secondary" class="form-control " id="secondary" ng-model="secondary" ng-options="s.skill_name for s in skills| excludeFrom:primary"></select>
    <div ng-controller="profileController">
        <input type="button" value="Search" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary" ng-model="searchbtn" name="search" ng-click="profileController.getprofile()">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Primary skill1</th>
                <th>Primary skill2</th>
                <th>Primary skill3</th>
                <th>Secondary skill1</th>
                <th>Secondary skill2</th>
                <th>Secondary skill3</th>
                <th>Secondary skill4</th>
                <th>Secondary skill5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in profiles">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function profileController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getprofile = function() {
        var pskill = $("#primary").val();
        var skill = $("#secondary").val();
        $http({
                url: "{{PROFILE_REPOSITORY}}",
                method: "POST",
                data: { "_token": { { csrf_token() } }, 'primary': pskill, 'secondary': skill },
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.profiles = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            }),
            function(response) {
                console.log('failed');
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `ng-click = "getprofile()"` Try this it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="primary" style="padding-right:5px">Primary skill </label>
    <select id="primary" class="form-control" ng-model="primary" id="primary" ng-options="s.skill_name for s in skills| excludeFrom:secondary"></select>
    <label for="secondary">Secondary skill </label>
    <select id="secondary" class="form-control " id="secondary" ng-model="secondary" ng-options="s.skill_name for s in skills| excludeFrom:primary"></select>
    <div ng-controller="profileController">
        <input type="button" value="Search" class="mx-sm-3 btn btn-primary" ng-model="searchbtn" name="search" ng-click="getprofile()">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Primary skill1</th>
                <th>Primary skill2</th>
                <th>Primary skill3</th>
                <th>Secondary skill1</th>
                <th>Secondary skill2</th>
                <th>Secondary skill3</th>
                <th>Secondary skill4</th>
                <th>Secondary skill5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in profiles">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function profileController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getprofile = function() {
        var pskill = $("#primary").val();
        var skill = $("#secondary").val();
        $http({
                url: "{{PROFILE_REPOSITORY}}",
                method: "POST",
                data: { "_token": { { csrf_token() } }, 'primary': pskill, 'secondary': skill },
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.profiles = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            }),
            function(response) {
                console.log('failed');
            }
    }
}
</script>
```